# Which plugin (npm) to use for localization in NativeScript?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

Which plugin (npm) to use for localization in NativeScript and Angular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[nativescript-localize](https://github.com/lfabreges/nativescript-localize) implements the native way of localizing iOS / Android apps.

```
tns plugin add nativescript-localize
```

If you like to find any plugins, you can simply do a search at https://market.nativescript.org/ Checkout the number downloads / recent releases to understand the popularity / stability of the plugin.

**Note:** At present this plugin doesn't support switching the language within your app, it always picks up the default language of the device which is more generic way of handling localization with mobile apps.

If you prefer to control the language selection within your app, you may have to go with any angular specific plugins to manage your language.

Comment: Could you share an sample how to use and where to pass this dependency?

Comment: It's all documented well in the plugin, please refer there.

Comment: It seems that the support for nativescript-localize is not up to date for nativescript 8. Any alternatives?

Comment: Checkout https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/localize.html

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `ngx-translate` for you NativeScript project. All other plugins implements native i18n, so you can't change the application language on **runtime**. Because they depend on the os language.

Most of the time we use English as our os language but doesn't necessarily mean our native language is English. [Here](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) you go.